# What diference between -Dconfig.resource and -Dconfig.file in akka?

Tags: scala, akka, config, typesafe-config

[According to the Akka Configuration documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/configuration.html#Reading_configuration_from_a_custom_location):

What is the difference between the `-Dconfig.resource` and `-Dconfig.file` arguments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

System properties can be used to force a different config source:

- `config.resource` specifies a resource name - not a basename, i.e. application.conf not application
- `config.file` specifies a filesystem path, again it should include the extension, not be a basename
- `config.url` specifies a URL

Loading configuration with `-Dconfig.file` is the way to specify an external file to load,

`-Dconfig.resource` - for internal resources.

Taken from: [Configuration file syntax and features](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Configuration).