# provide external config files in scala application

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, configuration, akka, typesafe

In IntelliJ, I exported a scala/akka project using "dist". 
That ends in a zip file, under

```
foo\target\universal\foo-1.0.0.zip
```

When I unzip the file, I get following directory structure:

```
D:.
├───bin
│       foo
│       foo.bat
│
└───lib
        a.jar
        b.jar
        com.foo.jar
        ...
        x.jar
```

In command line, I'm trying to run the `foo.bat`, but I'd like to provide external config files.

I'd like to use e.g. `application.conf.prod` and `logback.xml.prod`, to override the `application.conf` and `logback.xml` files in the `com.foo.jar` file

I'm using the following versions (copying part of `build.sbt`):

```
version := "1.0.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.9"
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % "2.4.9"
"ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.6"
"org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "0.10.0.0"
```

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: there's a [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17623936/3380951) about using external `reference.conf`, but my question is for `application.conf` and `logback.xml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do this by passing arguments when running your jvm application.

- For the `application.conf` you can use `-Dconfig.file=/your/path/application.conf`
- For `LogBack` you can use `-Dlogback.configurationFile="/your/path/logback.xml"`

Comment: this works for me. some related answers: [logback](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19519216/3380951) ([official doc](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html)), and [akka config](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27355750/3380951)

Comment: Related note: [log4j](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7927278/3380951) is different with the `file:` prefix